# Unable to fetch data in request.form in flask

Tags: html, flask

I am using flask as the backend and i have my html template as

```
<div id="tablediv">
  <form action="{{ url_for('useraction') }}" method="post">
  <table class="table" id="displaytable">
    <thead>
      <tr>
        <th scope="col">Name</th>
        <th scope="col">Email</th>
        <th scope="col">Address</th>
        <th scope="col">Action</th>
      </tr>
    </thead>
    <tbody>
      {%for i in range(0, len)%}
      <tr>
        <td id="username" name = "username">{{unverifieduser[i][1]}}</td>
        <td id="useremail" name="useremail">{{unverifieduser[i][2]}}</td>
        <td id="useraddress" name="useraddress">{{unverifieduser[i][3]}}</td>
        <td >
          <button type="submit" class="btn btn-danger" id="delete" name="delete">Delete</button>
          <button type="submit" class="btn btn-warning" id="verify" name="verify">Verify</button>
        </td>
      </tr>
      {%endfor%}
    </tbody>
  </table>
  </form>
</div>
```

My API call looks like

```
@app.route('/useraction', methods = ['GET', 'POST'])
def useraction():
    print(request.form)
    if request.method =='POST':
        cursor = mysql.connection.cursor()
        cursor.execute('SELECT * FROM user where isVerified = false');
        user = cursor.fetchall()
    return render_template('user.html', len = len(user), unverifieduser = user)
```

The output gives only the button which i click for example 'verify'

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/szrQt.png)

Is there any html attribute I am missing to get all the elements of the table for example username, useremail, useraddress

Answer (score 0):

An HTML table or HTML table elements are not `Form` elements. In HTML, only `Form` elements are sent along with such a `POST` request. [Here](https://www.w3schools.com/html/html_form_elements.asp) is an overview of all HTML `Form` elements. Note that these elements should be inside a `form` element, which is in your case the following line:

`<form action="{{ url_for('useraction') }}" method="post">`

As for why you only have `verify` in your form: the sole other input element in your form is the `delete` button, with its type set to `submit`. While you can have multiple `submit` buttons, only the one you click is sent along with the form.